# Magento 2.4.2 : Owl Carousel in Related Products not working

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, related-products, owl-carousel

I am facing a strange issue with setup owl carousel slider to related products on PDP. I've added below code to initialise owl carousel at the end of `items.phtml` file in my custom theme.

`app/design/frontend/My_Vendor/mytheme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list/items.phtml`

```
<script>
    require([ 'jquery', 'owl.carousel'], function($){
        $(document).ready(function($) {
            $('#related').owlCarousel({
                loop:false, 
                nav: true,
                margin:28,
                dots: true,    
                responsive:{
                    0:{
                        items:3,
                        margin:15
                    },
                    1025:{
                        items:4,
                        margin:28   
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

It initialize the owl carousel on the element but element nesting is in wrong order as shown in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYGLj.png)

As you can see all the images are nested under one `owl-item` div, which is breaking the layout and product block is displaying one after one as like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BuAIf.jpg)

I've debugged code in `items.phtml` and when I remove

`data-shuffle-group="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getPriority()) ?>"`

from the code on **line no 204** it is displaying related product slider without any issue.

So I am not sure about what is the purpose of this code and why it is causing the issue.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please help me :- https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/336115/85907

Answer (score 1):

in vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/web/js/related-products.js, there's a function _shuffle rearranging the products based on the data-shuffle-group attribute. If this function is called after the owl carousel initialized, it will append the product div one after another, so all product item divs are in one div. I think the best solution is to initialize owl carousel after related-products.js